# turn string of hexadecimal numbers into cmyk reference?

Tags: java, hex, processing, wav, cmyk

i have a huge file of hexadecimal numbers, from a wav file I opened in a hex editor. Is there a code (i'm using processing) to turn a string of these numbers into a cmyk reference?

My tutor mentioned perhaps writing a code that takes every 4 or so numbers from the hex editor and turns them into a cmyk reference. (i could do this manually but it would take years) I'm somewhat inexperienced with processing so would appreciate the help!

edit: i'm currently taking 8 digit blocks from the editor and putting it into the code to turn it into a colour. Processing then produces a coloured square. I hope to find a code to automate processing to process more than 8 at a time, as i'm doing this for an entire wav file opened in the editor.

Comment: java.lang.Integer.parseInt(String,radix) + reading the file and substringing it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to convert hex values from sound into color? Some kind of art project?

Comment: Exactly, this is for a design project. I noticed in the hex editor numbers came in columns of 4 and thought it could be translated into a cmyk ref.

Comment: turn into a color how? Are you pretending the hex print is of a specific order? e.g. eight characters representing 'RRGGBBAA'?

Answer (score 0):

In plain Processing you can use `unhex()` to turn your string into an int, after which you can use `str()` to turn the int into a String character. Java can do this more efficiently, but falling back to plain Java means you won't be able to run your code in non-JVM environments (like on the web)

Comment: okay, so far i have:

String hs = "48865966";
int hi = unhex(hs);
fill(hi);
rect(30, 20, 55, 55);

which gives a coloured square.
so i'm still taking 8 numbers at a time and pasting them into processing.

is it possible to take more (a whole hex file?) and have it output the colours?

Comment: you're going to have to update your OP, then, to explain exactly how many bytes per "thing" you expect. Normally you do 2 byte hex->int conversion, if you're using larger hex strings, explain what you think they represent, and I'll update my answer to match.

Comment: i'd looking for a code to take more numbers and use them in the same process, one that takes numbers at a time to produce more coloured squares.